# como hacer una llamada http al enviar formulario en angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

tengo problemas para hacer una llamada http al enviar un formulario mediante Angular, el problema es que no se como pasarle un parámetro y tampoco se si estoy haciendo bien la llamada, lo que quiero es que se haga la llamada HTTP con el parametro que se escribe en el label del formulario.
El php devuelve un json que se pinta en tablaResul .

Código Html:

```
<form id="form1" class="contacto" ng-submit="search()" >
<h3>Formulario de búsqueda</h3>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
<table id="buscador">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar aqu&iacute;..." required ng-model="nombreLibro">
            <button type="submit" >Buscar</button>
        </td>

    </tr>
 </table>

</br></br>


<table id="tablaResul">
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x.autor }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.nombre }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.fecha_publicacion }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Script con la función en el controlador que no devuelve nada:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.search = function() {
        $http({
            url: "consulta.php", 
            method: "GET",
            params: {name: $scope.nombreLibro}
         }).then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
    }
});
</script>
```

Script que funciona correctamente gracias al cual se que se hace bien la llamada HTTP y me pinta en tablaResul la informacion que devuelve el php:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $http({
        url: "consulta.php", 
        method: "GET",
        params: {name: "1984"}
     }).then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});

});
</script>
```

Comment: Haz probado hacerle un `console.log` a `$scope.nombreLibro` justo antes de hacer la petición. Tu código no parece tener problemas.

Comment: Lo acabo de hacer y me devuelve undefined, no tiene acceso a la variable del modelo...

Comment: veo que falta cerrar el `<div>` donde declaras el ng-controller, esto causa problemas en algunos browsers, te recomiendo que lo cierres correctamente., deberias agregar `</div>` justo antes de cerrar el form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<form id="form1" class="contacto" method="POST">
  <h3>Formulario de búsqueda</h3>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
    <table id="buscador">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar aqu&iacute;..." required ng-model="nombreLibro">
          <button type="submit" ng-click="search(nombreLibro)">Buscar</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </br></br>

    <table id="tablaResul">
      <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
        <td>{{ x.autor }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.nombre }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.fecha_publicacion }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

Script

```
<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.search = function(nombreLibro) {
        $http({
          url: "consulta.php", 
          method: "GET",
          params: {name: nombreLibro}
        }).then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
      }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto, muchas gracias